# Is it possible to implement a class in such a way that it would be possible to value initialize it as if it was POD

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a class (let's name it `TheClass`) that is quite often used in the following situation: several instances are constructed from constants and passed as several arguments to some other constructor. Unfortunately I have to use quite cumbersome syntax for the initialization:

```
Otherclass{ TheClass{1, 'a', 2}, 
            TheClass{1, 'b', 4},
            TheClass{3, 'h', 2}, 
            TheClass{1, 't', 8} }
```

Is there a way to make it possible to initialize the class as if it was POD? I.e. I want to be able to write

```
Otherclass{ {1, 'a', 2}, 
            {1, 'b', 4},
            {3, 'h', 2}, 
            {1, 't', 8} }
```

**Edit**: I've posted another question with the correct definition of the problem I'm facing. Please see [Is it possible to pass data as initializer_list to std::array of structures?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8839639/283145)

Comment: Let's just say I have much more complicated case (templates and such). I'll update the question with a minimal not-working case, since the above obviously works.

Comment: Note that your terminology is a bit off -- what you're describing is not value-initialization, but aggregate-initialization.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do what you want. Alternatively you can `typedef TheClass t;` or define a macro like this: `#define _(x) TheClass x` and `#undef` it afterwards.

```
#include <initializer_list>
class TheClass {
public:
  TheClass(int x, char y, int z) { }
};

class OtherClass {
public:
  OtherClass(std::initializer_list<TheClass> t) { }
};

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
  OtherClass s { {1,'a',2}, {1, 'b', 4}, {3, 'h', 2}, {1, 't', 8}};
  return 0;
}
```