# Is it possible to pass data as initializer_list to std::array of structures?

Tags: c++, constructor, c++11, initializer-list

I have the following code. Basically I want to initialize a std::array of non-POD structs using aggregate initialization syntax. Both g++ 4.6 and 4.7 (latest weekly snapshot) fails to compile the code.

```
#include <array>

struct TheClass {

    int a1, a2;

    TheClass(int b1, int b2) : a1{b1}, a2{b2} {};    
};

template<unsigned D>
struct OtherClass {

    std::array<TheClass, D> a;

    OtherClass(std::array<TheClass, 2> b) : a{b} {};
};

int main()
{
    OtherClass<2>{{ {1, 2}, {2, 3} }}; //tried a lot of options here
}
```

GCC errors:

```
v.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
v.cpp:20:37: error: no matching function for call to ‘OtherClass<2u>::OtherClass(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
v.cpp:20:37: note: candidates are:
v.cpp:15:5: note: OtherClass<D>::OtherClass(std::array<TheClass, 2ul>) [with unsigned int D = 2u]
v.cpp:15:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘std::array<TheClass, 2ul>’
v.cpp:11:8: note: constexpr OtherClass<2u>::OtherClass(const OtherClass<2u>&)
v.cpp:11:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘const OtherClass<2u>&’
v.cpp:11:8: note: constexpr OtherClass<2u>::OtherClass(OtherClass<2u>&&)
v.cpp:11:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘OtherClass<2u>&&’
```

My questions: is the above code correct? It seems that as std::array is an aggregate, there should be no problems to construct its data members. Maybe it's a bug in GCC?

**EDIT**:

`OtherClass<2>{{ TheClass{1, 2}, TheClass{2, 3} }};` works of course, but I don't want to use that as I have to construct the class in a lot of places. C++11 should support omission of `TheClass`. Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8838636/is-it-possible-to-implement-a-class-in-such-a-way-that-it-would-be-possible-to-v).

Comment: Did you try `OtherClass<2>{{{ TheClass {1, 2}, TheClass {2, 3} }}};`?

Comment: Please see updated question. Of course that works, but C++11 should support the omission of `TheClass`.

Comment: Your update doesn't include the extra set of braces from my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::array` is an aggregate *containing* an array, so you need an extra pair of braces to initialise it from a regular array:

```
{1,2}               // TheClass
{{1,2},{2,3}}       // TheClass[2]
{{{1,2},{2,3}}}     // std::array<TheClass,2>
{{{{1,2},{2,3}}}}   // OtherClass<2>
```

However, it seems that older versions of GCC still stuggle with this: [4.5.1 rejects it](http://ideone.com/aWTVo), while 4.6.1 accepts it.

Comment: @jons34yp: It works for me with GCC 4.6.1, but not with earlier versions.

Comment: Finally, C++ gets a bit of the Lisp spirit.

Comment: I think this is an inconsistency in the standard. On the one hand, it says: "An array is an aggregate (8.5.1) that can be initialized with the syntax
array<T, N> a = { initializer-list };
where initializer-list is a comma-separated list of up to N elements whose types are convertible to T." But that is not the case here, it requires those extra braces that are in fact implied by other parts of the standard.

Comment: @Juho, the standard only allows to omit braces in a declaration of the form `type var = { ... }`. In this case, we are not having such a declaration, so you must specify all braces. This requirement is currently under discussion in a wg21 core issue.

Comment: @Johannes, do you mean that `std::array<TheClass,2> m = {{1,2},{3,4}};` should work? It doesn't, it requires one pair of braces more, that is because it is an aggregate initialization with one array as a member. I wondered why either literal types (arrays of `int`) or explicitly constructed objects (`TheClass {1,2}`) still work without extra braces. I think it is because of elision rule for subaggregates (§8.5.1 paragraph 11, C++2011). That is, unless full braces are written, the syntax would be ambiguous when member objects themselves use list-initialization without explicit constructors.