# Difference between constructors with parameters and without

Tags: c++, constructor

Here are two classes

```
class A
{
    std::string s;
public:
    A() { prn("A constructor"); }
    A(std::string s) : s(s) { prn("A not empty constructor"); }
    A(const A&) { prn("A copy constructor"); }
    A& operator =(const A& a) { prn("A = operator"); return *this; }
    void p() { prn("in A"); }
};

class B
{
public:
    A a;
    B(A aa) : a(aa) { prn("B constructor"); }
    B() { prn("B default constructor"); }
};
```

Now following code works correctly

```
B b(A("sa"));
b.a.p();
```

Prints:

> A not empty constructor
>   A copy constructor
>   B constructor
>   in A

But if I use A constructor without parameters something strange happens

```
B b(A());
```

Compiles and run but no output (No constructors have been called)

```
B b(A());
b.a.p(); // error here
```

Got compile error. So whats the difference between these two constructors?

Comment: You didn't call any constructor, even though you may have thought you did.

Comment: i think you should do like A a;B b(a); which works fine as expected. what you mentioned is function decl not object decl.

Answer (score 5):

```
B b(A());
```

This does not declare an object. It declares a function called `b`, with return type `B`, that takes a pointer to a function with return type `A` as an argument.

What you want is:

```
B b = A();
```

or (thanks Kerrek):

```
B b((A()));
```

or in C++11:

```
B b {A()};
```

This is sometimes known as a [vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

Comment: Simply `B b((A()));` will do. A [little lisp](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8839746/596781) has never hurt anyone.

Comment: [Another lisp reference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6298050/636019) ;-] Also, a more consistent C++11 version would be `B b{A{}};`.

Comment: Thanks. Got it. B b = A(); wont work if B() is declared explicit. But    B b((A())); works fine in both cases.

Comment: The compile error should have made it clear that you declared `b` as a function, not a class instance. Mine (G++) gave: `request for member a in b, which is of non-class type B(A (*)())`.